# cannot find function `get_platform` in sdl2 0.31.0

Tags: rust, sdl-2

I'm using the latest version of sdl2 (0.31.0) but cannot access [`get_platform`](https://rust-sdl2.github.io/rust-sdl2/sdl2/fn.get_platform.html):

```
extern crate sdl2;

pub fn main() {
    println!("{}", sdl2::get_platform());
}
```

```
$ cargo run
   Compiling repro v0.1.0 (file:///private/tmp/repro)
error[E0425]: cannot find function `get_platform` in module `sdl2`
 --> src/main.rs:4:30
  |
4 |         println!("{}", sdl2::get_platform());
  |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in `sdl2`
```

I tried with `use sdl2::*;` and with `cargo +nightly run`, but neither removed the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation you are reading is is not for the version you are using. Build it yourself (`cargo doc --open`) or [view it on docs.rs](https://docs.rs/sdl2/0.31.0/sdl2/).

That function was [added recently](https://github.com/Rust-SDL2/rust-sdl2/commit/07723632dfa7a019ab4d3e153dc9b808337460fd) and has not been released yet. Perhaps you should file an issue for the authors of the crate to let them know that having documentation that doesn't correspond to any released code is confusing.

In the meantime, you can use [a git dependency](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-dependencies-from-git-repositories) if you really need it.